# Unexpected C++ behaviour in the following program

Tags: polymorphism

I came across some dodgy code recently. But the behavior left me a bit dumbfounded. The following is a simplification of the problem (basically the virtual keyword is missing, making it non-polymorphic). Why/how is it printing "C::foo called, i: 5"?

How is the object in memory even able to have 'i' in it? I tried C++03 and C++11.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class P
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout << "P::foo called" << endl;
    }
};

class C : public P
{
public:
    void foo()
    {
        i = 5;
        cout << "C::foo called, i: " << i << endl;
    }

    int i;
};

int main()
{
    C* c = static_cast<C*>(new P());
    c->foo();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why/how is it printing "C::foo called, i: 5"?"

In static_casting the P pointer to a C pointer you're saying to the complier interpret this bit of memory as if it contained an object of class C

So when you call foo on that it looks up Cs version of foo.

(That explains the C:foo called... but not how i is 5)

"How is the object in memory even able to have 'i' in it"

In a way it doesn't. Having been told that this memory contains a C, the complier then "knows" that i lives at a certain memory offset from the objects this pointer. That memory hasn't been allocated especially to contain an i member for an object of type C (no objects of C have been created) but having been told (wrongly) that the memory does contain a C, it'll use that address as i, and, because you set it in foo before you output it, that misappropriated address will end up containing 5.

If you don't set i in foo, but you initialise it when its declared instead, you'd see that a real C object outputs the value you set it to, but that a P* cast as a C* outputs whatever happens to be at that address.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the expected behaviour, nothing strange with it.
"Notes
static_cast may also be used to disambiguate function overloads by performing a function-to-pointer conversion to specific type"

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

---

I'm not able yo verify right now, but in an instance of a child object you should be able to specify which of the two "foo" you want to call by specifying the namespace. Not sure about that when a static cast occurs though.

```
void C::foo()
{
  if (/*something*/)
     // do something
  else
     D::foo();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After much research the conclusion: "undefined behaviour"

Here is the rule for downcasting using `static_cast`, found in section 5.2.9 (`[expr.static.cast]`) of the C++ standard (C++0x wording):

> A prvalue of type "pointer to *cv1* `B`", where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type "pointer to *cv2* `D`", where `D` is a class derived from `B`, if a valid standard conversion from "pointer to `D`" to "pointer to `B`" exists, *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and `B`
>   is neither a virtual base class of `D` nor a base class of a virtual base class of `D`. The null pointer value is converted to the null pointer value of the destination type. If the prvalue of type "pointer to *cv1* `B`" points
>   to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object
>   of type `D`. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.

ref:- [Downcasting using the 'static_cast' in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322949/downcasting-using-the-static-cast-in-c)