# C++ Sub Classes Share Variable?

Tags: c++

Noob to C++. I countered a weird issue when playing with inheritance in C++. I have a Parent class, and 2 child class that inherit Parent class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Parent {
  public:
    Parent() {}
};

class Child1: public Parent {
  public:
    int param1;
    Child1(int param): Parent() {
      param1 = param;
    }
};

class Child2: public Parent {
  public:
    int param2;
    Child2(int param): Parent() {
      param2 = param;
    }
};

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<Parent> obj = std::make_shared<Child1>(123);

  std::cout << std::static_pointer_cast<Child2>(obj)->param2 << std::endl;
  // output 123 and no run time error, wut?

  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, although `obj` is initialized with `Child1`'s constructor, it can still be cased to `Child2`. Event `param2` has the same value as `param1`.

What's going on here? Is there a term for this kind of behavior? Is this special to `shared_ptr`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, the duplicate doesn't discuss shared_ptr, but that is immaterial. The shared_ptr is just an indirection step to doing this static_cast. Consult the duplicate for a thorough explanation.

Comment: @StoryTeller It is related, but not really a duplicate (assuming OP does not know `std::static_pointer_cast` is performing a `static_cast` downcast).

Comment: @Acorn - There's a big hint that it does. And I beg to differ, the shared_ptr is just a red herring.

Comment: @StoryTeller For you/me, indeed. For beginners searching information about `std::static_pointer_cast`, not really. A comment with a link to the other question is good enough, but an actual answer explaining the entire reasoning is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [util.smartptr.shared.cast], `std::static_pointer_cast` returns:

```
shared_ptr<T>(r, static_cast<typename shared_ptr<T>::element_type*>(r.get()))
```

This means that, effectively, you are performing an `static_cast` from `Parent *` to `Child2 *`. That is fine.

However, in this case, the object you are casting, `obj`, has runtime type `Child1 *`, [so you end up with undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322949/), according to [expr.static.cast]p11:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B”, where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D”, where D is a class derived from B, if cv2 is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1. (...) If the prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is **actually a subobject** of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: "You wouldn't be able to do a normal static_cast from one to the other"

is this because I'm using smart pointer? what does it mean by "normal"? is there a abnormal one? thanks!

Comment: @Daiwei No, the problem is trying to do a `static_cast` to an unrelated type, i.e. an invalid downcast. See e.g. [Downcasting using the 'static_cast' in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322949/) for details.

Comment: @Daiwei I have edited the answer to give you more (formal) details.