# Error while accessing derived class resources by base class object

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I have base class called Base and a derived class of Base called Derived,
A Base Class pointer can point to a derived class object and can also access its resource but I am getting an error doing the same.

```
class Base
{
public:
    int a;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    float b;
    void DoSomething()
    {
         cout<<"Derived";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base * pBase = new Derived();
    pBase->DoSomething();
    pBase->a = 5; 
    pBase->b = 0.2f; 
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me an error

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:34:25: error: ‘class Base’ has no member named ‘DoSomething’
     pBase->DoSomething();
                         ^
main.cpp:36:12: error: ‘class Base’ has no member named ‘b’
     pBase->b = 0.2f;
            ^
```

Pardon me if its too basics, I am a beginner in c++

Comment: If you are using a `Derived` as a `Base`, it is limited by what `Base` knows. `Base` has no `DoSomething` so `Base` cannot use `DoSomething`.

Comment: But see this `Base * pBase = new Derived();` we can do this. I have studied that this is allowed i.e A base class pointer can store reference to its derived class

Comment: `Derived` [is-a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Base`. It knows everything `Base` knows, and can be used as a `Base`. But `Base` cannot know what `Derived` knows. That `Base*` could be pointing to a `Derived` and it could be pointing at an `AlsoDerived`, which has different functionality. [Look into `virtual` methods](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) if you want behaviour in `Base` that may be specified by classes derived from `Base`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a `Base` pointer to a `Derived` class, nonetheless, the `Base` pointer must know the methods in order to choose what's the most suited for the call, if the `Base` pointer has no knowledge of the existence of these variables and functions it cannot call them.

[Corrected code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZuYMT9ybMiosCW3P):

```
class Base
{
public:
    int a;
    float b;
    virtual ~Base(){} //virtual destructor required
    virtual void DoSomething() //implementing DoSomething in base class
    {
        std::cout << "Base";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void DoSomething() override //override DoSomething() in base class
    {
         std::cout<<"Derived";
    }
};
```

```
Base * pBase = new Derived();
//Base will choose the most suited DoSomething(), depending where it's pointing to
pBase->DoSomething(); 
pBase->a = 5;
pBase->b = 0.2f;
```

Output:

```
Derived
```

**Edit:**

As you suggested in the comment section, casting the derived class will work in this specific case, but it usually reveals poorly designed code, as pointed out by [@user4581301's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200791/error-while-accessing-derived-class-resources-by-base-class-object/62201083#comment110009137_62201083), also note the [link provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322949/downcasting-using-the-static-cast-in-c) that has some of the reasons why this is not the best idea.

As I said, if you must do it, use `dynamic_cast<>()` instead.

Note that, in any case, you still need the virtual destructor for a correct implementaion of polymorphism.

> Virtual destructors
>
> Deleting an object through pointer to base invokes undefined behavior unless the destructor in the base class is virtual.

and that's not all, check [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: After little bit of research I found that I was looking for static cast `static_cast<Derived*>(pBase)->DoSomething();` if you could edit your answer explaining the same I could accept answer to this question. Also could you mention is there any cons of doing this way

Comment: @FarhanAhmed You should avoid casting from base to derived. Sometimes you must, but much, much more often you have a flaw in the design. If you have to do this a lot, the classes should not have an inheritance relationship at all.

Comment: @FarhanAhmed, though this works in this specific case it's not at all recommended to do it, this most certainly lead to very poorly designed code, but if you must do it, `dynamic_cast` is better.

Comment: Consider this: In order to use a cast in this manner you must know with absolute certainty the `Base*` points to a `Derived`, and if you know this with absolute certainty, why are you using `Base` at all?

Comment: @FarhanAhmed, I added some further info to my answer, be sure to check it out.